# Cross site collection lookup field (SPO)

Tags: sharepoint-online, lookup-column, site-collection, spo

I need to create "cross site collection lookup field" in the SharePoint Online List.
I can programmatically change "List" and "WebId" in SchemaXml from LookUp field. It helps to get "cross site" lookup, but not "cross site collection".
I got an exception "Microsoft. SharePoint.Client.ServerException: 'File Not Found.'" when I tried to save changes in SchemaXml for "cross site collection".

Is it possible to create "cross site collection" lookup programmatically? If yes then how?

Or I should learn how to work with SPFx and how to change List and get a lookup through REST API?

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint does not support lookups pointing to other sites. But you can take a look at 3-rd party solution - [Plumsail Forms](https://plumsail.com/forms/sharepoint-forms/). It allows you to [link lists from different sites](https://plumsail.com/docs/forms-sp/how-to/csl.html) and emulate behavior of a lookup field with a regular text field with built-in field customizers.